# How to skip symfony2 warning message

Tags: php, symfony

I try to introduce an error 500 header in the catch part of the try. I'm calling my API method in a symfony controller method via Ajax. My issue is that I can't display the error message because of this symfony warning page

[image]

Here's the API side code :

```
try{
           //Some code 

        }catch (Exception $e){
            header('HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error');
            die($e->getMessage()); // I get this message in the error part of the ajax call
        }
```

Controller method :

```
public function createModelAction(){

    $mail = "test";
    $pass = "test";

    $oauth = new OAuth($mail, $pass);

    $baseUrl = $this->container->getParameter('url_api');

    // Récupération des rapports d'avis du réseau demandé
    $link = "{$baseUrl}model/" . $mail . "/" . $pass . "/test";

    $oauth->fetch($link, $_REQUEST, OAUTH_HTTP_METHOD_POST);
    $response = json_decode($oauth->getLastResponse(), true);

    if ($response['error']) {
        return new JsonResponse($response['error']);
    } else {
        return new JsonResponse($response['model']);
    }
}
```

So any alternative to skip this problem.

Thanks

Comment: Can you show your Controler?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Symfony Request and Response rather than use `header` manually.

Change the code from your API to :

```
} catch (Exception $e) {
    $response['error'] = $e->getMessage();

    return $response;
}
```

In your controller, define the status code of your response :

```
if ($response['error']) {
    return new JsonResponse($response['error'], 500);
}
```

You can also look for create an [ExceptionListener](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/event_dispatcher/event_listener.html#creating-an-event-listener) and return a JsonResponse instead of throw the exception.